# How to sudo apt-get install all latex CJK?

Tags: installation, 12.10, apt, latex

Is there a way to just install latex packages with `sudo apt-get install` ??
like for https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/latex-cjk-chinese/ and also the japanese and korean ones?

I'm on ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a package called `latex-cjk-all` it is a meta package that will install all the CJK Packages.

```
sudo apt-get install latex-cjk-all
```

You can see its description with

```
apt-cache show latex-cjk-all
```

> Description-en: installs all LaTeX CJK packages
>   This package will install all CJK packages.
>   You may also wish to install each package separately instead.
>   See the latex-cjk-common package for a detailed description.

Had the `latex-cjk-all` package not been available, you could have also run

```
sudo apt-get install latex-cjk-*
```

This will install all packages starting with `latex-cjk-`